# Another Input Past end of file error

Tags: vbscript, hta

I know what causes this, but I'm not sure what I need in my situation to fix it.  Someone else here wrote the code (or borrowed it), but I keep getting the error in my script at line 63 character 3.  Notice the `ReadAll` in that line.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
  APPLICATIONNAME="UPSApp" 
  ICON=".\UPS.ico"
  SCROLL="no"
  BORDER="thin"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes">

<script language="VBScript">
Const strStatusFile = "C:\Zscript\fswstatus\fswStatus.txt"

Dim intTimerID
intTimerID = window.setInterval("RunAtInterval", 1000)

Sub Window_onLoad
  Dim intWidth, intHeight

  intWidth = 400
  intHeight = 200

  Me.resizeTo intWidth, intHeight
  Me.moveTo ((Screen.Width / 2) - (intWidth / 2)), ((Screen.Height / 2) - (intHeight / 2))
End Sub

Sub RunAtInterval
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If Not objFSO.FileExists(strStatusFile) Then Exit Sub
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strStatusFile, 1, True)

  strContent = objFile.ReadAll
  strContent = Replace(strContent, vbLf, "<br>")

  If strContent = "QUIT" Then
    window.Close
  Else
    document.formStatus.innerHTML = strContent & "<br>"
  End If
End Sub

<form name = "formStatus"
```

Comment: Another possible duplicate [Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Input past end of file error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26878933/692942)

Comment: Reading by line in a loop which will give you more control and allow for checking like `Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream`. Especially recommended if you are trying to read a large file as `objFile.ReadAll()` isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is empty/has a length of 0. Evidence:

```
>> n = ".\nix.txt"
>> goFS.CreateTextFile n
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile(n).Size
>> goFS.OpenTextFile(n).ReadAll()
>>
0
Error Number:       62
Error Description:  Input past end of file
```

Update wrt comment:

As it makes no sense to read from an empty file, you shouldn't try to. Check for a size of 0 and do what's reasonable in your use case.

Comment: That's what I was driving toward with the ReadAll reference, what is the best way to work around that, based on the the code above?

Comment: How many times do you need [to answer the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26880789/692942)?, just flag it as a dup and move on.